# jQuery replace day input to 00 if higher than 31

Tags: jquery, replace, keyup

I am currently working on a age verification page and I need to make a jQuery script that will check if the date is correct, go to the next input and validate the user.

```
//Age Verification
$('.inp .day, .inp .month, .inp .year').on('keyup', function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
});
$('.inp .day').on('keyup', function () {
    if (this.value >= 32) {
        this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
    } if (this.value.length >= 2) {
        $('.inp .month').focus();
    }

});
$('.inp .month').on('keyup', function () {
    if (this.value >= 13) {
        this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
    }
    if (this.value.length >= 2) {
        $('.inp .year').focus();
    }
});
```

This is what i have created and it works just fine except for the two if statements for day (`if (this.value >= 32)`) and month (`if (this.value >= 13)`).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: What's the expected result?  What's happening instead?  Explicitness is key!

Comment: Nothing.. i get no error.. nothing.. maybe .replace isn't the correct way of doing this :/

Comment: It would help if you could spend a little bit of time trying to narrow in on the problem.  What are you trying to check for to validate?

Comment: what i need is to change the value to 'nothing' if the users types in the input a higher value than 31

Comment: It looks like you're overthinking this a bit, yes.  Take a look at the two answers, I think they should be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shouldn't

```
if (this.value >= 32) {
    this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
```

be

```
if (this.value >= 32) {
    this.value = 0;
```

?

I don't see how the value >= 32 is being asked to do anything different than

```
$('.inp .day, .inp .month, .inp .year').on('keyup', function () {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
});
```

is already doing

Comment: `value >= 32` is checking if the number entered is bigger than the max. It then needs to be set to 0. You're right about it not doing anything different right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.inp .day').on('keyup', function () {
    if(this.value > 31)
    {
        this.value = "00";
    }
    else if (this.value.length >= 2) {
        $('.inp .month').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: pfff.. worked about 2 hours in this problem and had no result XD... thanks alot man

Answer (score 0):

try

```
//Age Verification
$('.inp .day, .inp .month, .inp .year').on('keyup', function () {
    var $this = $this,
        thisVal = $this.val().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, '');
    $this.val(thisVal);
});
$('.inp .day').on('keyup', function () {
    var $this = $this,
        thisVal = $this.val();
    if (thisVal >= 32) {
        $this.val('');// or whatever it should be...31?
    }else if (thisVal.length >= 2) {
        $('.inp .month').focus();
    }

});
$('.inp .month').on('keyup', function () {
    var $this = $this,
        thisVal = $this.val();
    if (thisVal >= 13) {
        $this.val('');// or whatever it should be...12?
    }else if (this.value.length >= 2) {
        $('.inp .year').focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value to be nothing if the user types invalid data then why not just do this:

```
$('.inp .day, .inp .month, .inp .year').on('keyup', function () {
    this.value = ""; //Make it a blank string
});
$('.inp .day').on('keyup', function () {
    if (this.value >= 32) {
        this.value = ""; //Make it a blank string
    } if (this.value.length >= 2) {
        $('.inp .month').focus();
    }
});
$('.inp .month').on('keyup', function () {
    if (this.value >= 13) {
        this.value = "";//Make it a blank string
    }
    if (this.value.length >= 2) {
        $('.inp .year').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Sandy Gifford for the edit!  I moved too quickly with my answer

Comment: No worries, happens to the best of us.

Comment: And I mean, to be totally fair, the results would have been exactly the same given the way JavaScript stacks assignments. =)